# How to assign an json object identifier to a property

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a json string as follows

```
{"668":{"name":"Pink Ice","base_rgb":[128,26,26],
    "cloth":{"brightness":50,"contrast":1.36719,"hue":8,"saturation":0.351563,"lightness":1.36719,"rgb":[216,172,164]},
    "leather":{"brightness":47,"contrast":1.71875,"hue":8,"saturation":0.234375,"lightness":1.71875,"rgb":[207,170,163]},
    "metal":{"brightness":47,"contrast":1.64063,"hue":8,"saturation":0.429688,"lightness":1.48438,"rgb":[211,145,134]}}
```

I break this down into 1 Class with 1 nested class lets call them.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ColorEntry 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("base_rgb")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonColorConverter))]
        public Color BaseRGB { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cloth")]
        public ColorItemEntry Cloth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("leather")]
        public ColorItemEntry Leather { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("metal")]
        public ColorItemEntry Metal { get; set; }

        public class ColorItemEntry 
        {
            public ColorItemType Type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("brightness")]
            public int Brightness { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("contrast")]
            public double Contract { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("hue")]
            public int Hue { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("saturation")]
            public double Saturation { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("lightness")]
            public double Lightness { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("rgb")]
            [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonColorConverter))]
            public Color RGB { get; set; }

        }
    }
    public enum ColorItemType
    {
        Cloth,
        Leather,
        Metal,
    }
```

Can I assign the 668 to ColorEntry.ID and
ColorItemType.Cloth to ColorItemType.Type or
ColorItemType.Leather to ColorItemType.Type or
ColorItemType.Metal to ColorItemType.Type

without having to create a custom converter.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);      
  foreach (dynamic item in obj as System.Collections.IEnumerable)
  {
    var c = (ColorEntry)obj[item.Name].ToObject(typeof(ColorEntry));
    c.Id = int.Parse(item.Name);
  }
```

Comment: After using my custom Color Converter, it worked for part of the problem.  However, converting the subclass ColorItemEntry.Type value into the enum type of ColorItemType is still a problem.